# Maclaurin series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

What is the Maclaurin series of $$z^3\sin(z^2)$$

I'm able to differentiate it but can't figure out how to write it in general series form, can somebody help me please.

Comment: Do you know the series for $\sin(x)$?  Now... if you were to replace every occurrence of $x$ with $z^2$ instead, what does that look like?  Now if you were to multiply *that* series by $z^3$, what does that now look like?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that

$$\sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Thus,

$$\sin(z^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

and finally

$$z^3\sin(z^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{4n+5}}{(2n+1)!}$$